# Where can I find a good iPhone autorotation tutorial?

Tags: iphone

Can you guide me to where to find the best tutorial for autorotation for iPhone?

Comment: To autorotate an iPhone, put it on a record player. :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not a tutorial in the narrowest sense, but I find Apple's [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW3) explains interface rotation very well. If you read and understand these parts:

- Managing the Interface Orientation

  - Understanding the Rotation Process
  - Declaring the Supported Interface Orientations
  - Configuring Your Views to Support Multiple Orientations
  - Responding to Orientation Changes
  - Creating an Alternate Landscape Interface

you will know everything you need to know about the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Some gotchas with autorotation: http://blog.red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/iphone-auto-rotation-for-intermediate-developers-tutorial-1/